# Simple Injector register LibLog

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector, liblog

I am using the excellent [LibLog](https://github.com/damianh/LibLog) code for abstracting logger implementation in my application.

I am also using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) as my DI container.

I would like to inject an instance of logger in my classes which corresponds to the following static creation

```
private readonly ILog logger = LogProvider.For<MyClass>()
```

or if you like the static method

```
private readonly ILog logger = LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger()
```

Is it correct to do it this way?

```
container.Register<ILog>(() => LogProvider.GetCurrentClassLogger(), Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Or there is a better way ?

Edit:

```
  <package id="SimpleInjector" version="4.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="SimpleInjector.Packaging" version="4.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: My kingdom for "using" namespaces.  (If you get a chance to list them, that would be great.  Also "packages.config" to show the versions you're using when asking the question.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure I’ve got your question. If you mean namespaces of ILog interface as well as LogProvider class, then please have a look at the first link in the question, the one for the LibLog nuget. LibLog is a nuget that provide you with the source code so the namespace is of your project, I’ve added SimpleInjector versions. If I’m wrong, can you please let me better understand?

Comment: Yeah, I see it now.  This is the first time i've seen a nuget package bring in source-code......and not a precompiled assemby.  A little weird, but I "see" it now.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Registering LogLib is idential to how to [register log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25113659) and to [register nlog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34681834) with Simple Injector, and the documentation explains this as well [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection).

You need to make a conditional registration for `ILog` as follows:

```cs
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILog), 
    context => typeof(LibLogLog<>).MakeGenericType(context.Consumer.ImplementationType), 
    Lifestyle.Singleton, 
    context => true);
```

`LibLogLog<T>` is a generic class that forwards the call to `LogProvider.For<T>()`:

```cs
public sealed class LibLogLog<T> : ILog
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = LogProvider.For<T>();
    public bool Log(LogLevel l, Func<string> f, Exception e, params object[] p) =>
        logger.Log(l, f, e, p);
}
```

LibLog is actually one of the few logging libraries that designed their log interface correctly (i.e. with just one member). This makes it trivial to implement this `LibLogLog<T>` proxy.